# jQuery - run multiple methods sequentially

Tags: javascript, jquery, methods

if i do:

```
method();
method();
```

both calls will run in parallel (at same time)

i just would like to make the second method(); wait until the first method(); is finished before to start, and do it dynamically cause i can't know how many times i will launch method(); at same time .

Is it possible?

just for example, those runs at same time as i can see... http://jsfiddle.net/Lcgb8/

Comment: Javascript does not support multithreading.  Are you talking about AJAX? If so, use promises.

Comment: if you do what you describe in your code without using (fileReader,Xhr,Canvas or whatever is async) it will do it sequentially.your example executes sequentially.

Comment: @cocco indeed i need some tip to queue or stuffs like that, cause they are sync methods

Comment: so you want to wait until the next function executes?

Comment: yep exactly @cocco the next has to wait until the previous is fully executed

Comment: what does your function? like i said normal functions execute sequentially.. there must be something inyour function that breaks the sequence. in that case you could call the second function at the end of the first function (so inside & at the end of the first) and so on.. but that is not nice. if you tell us what breaks the sequence you could use different methods to execute it later.in that case the callbacks someone -- are the right answer.

Comment: I guess you need to modify your method and inside add a check at the end if it needs another call to itself.but with this two linesof code noone understand what you want. it's an animation?

Comment: if it's a css animation that breaks your sequence you can use the eventlistener 'transitionend'.

Comment: @cocco go ahead please :P any clue appriciated actually :P

Comment: i also thought to closures but uhmm don't know if i'm right

Comment: so it's an animation?

Comment: @cocco take this example http://jsfiddle.net/Lcgb8/

Comment: but think that method(); is called dinamycally in my case

Comment: @sbaaaang Have a look at my solution. It's probably the easiest one if you can modify the way `method` is implemented.

Comment: @plalx check this http://jsfiddle.net/Lcgb8/ _data is returned from a websocket so i can't now how many times and when method() will be called, the jsfiddle is just to show what i'm doing after received _data from a webscoket in my case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`then`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/) if you return a [`Deferred`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred/).

E.g.

```
function method() {
    var d = $.Deferred();

    //do something async
    setTimeout(function () {
        d.resolve('some data'); //inform listeners that the process is completed
    }, 2000);

    return d; //return the deferred object
}
```

Then you could do:

```
method().then(method).then(method).then(method);
```

Note that the return value of each call will be passed as first argument to the next call, respectively.

EDIT: Here's an example on how you could queue the async operations dynamically.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lcgb8/5/)

```
function changeColorAsync(color) {
    var d = $.Deferred();

    setTimeout(function () {
        $('body').css('background', color);

        d.resolve();

    }, 4000);

    return d;
}

$(function () {
    $('#color-form').on('submit', function (e) {
        var color = $(this).find(':checked').val(), d;

        d = d? 
            d.then(changeColorAsync.bind(this, color)) : 
            changeColorAsync(color);

        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: the problem is that i can't now how many time i will call method(); cause method() is called after a websocket received data

Comment: this is an example, where _data is returned from a websocket randomly http://jsfiddle.net/Lcgb8/

Comment: @plax i do not have this **var colors = ['red', 'blue', 'yellow']** since colors are returned from a webscoket randomly each random seconds

Comment: @sbaaaang, I don't see the problem? `var something = socketresult;`, then you process the result if it's a collection. If it's not it's even easier you simply have to keep a reference to the last `deferred`, let it be `d`, and you could just do `d.then(...)`

Comment: @sbaaaang Always keep a reference to the last `deferred` and it will become your entry point to queue the next operation. For first operation you do `var d = d? d.then(method) : method();`, then subsequent operations are just `d = d.then(...)`. It will effectively queue all async operations.

Comment: @sbaaaang I added an example of what I was trying to explain.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sequentially animation using `transitionend`

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>animation</title>
<style>
div{
width:50px;height:50px;background-color:#093;
-webkit-transition:all 300ms ease;
}
div.move{-webkit-transform:translate3d(200px,0,0);}/*GPU HW acceleration*/
</style>
<script>
(function(W){
 var D,d,L,c=0;
 function init(){
  D=W.document;d=D.getElementsByTagName('div');L=d.length;var l=d.length;
  while(l--){d[l].addEventListener('transitionend',next,false)}
  next();
 }
 function next(){
  d[c].classList[(d[c].className=='move'?'remove':'add')]('move');
  c++;c=(c==L?0:c);
 }
 W.addEventListener('load',init,false);
})(window)
</script>
</head>
<body><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div></body>
</html>
```

it had  little error fixed now..

supports infinite div's and it's infinite loop using low resources. =)

your `method()` would be my `next()`

if someone want's to jsfiddle it...  i don't use that.

ps.: pure javascript (no jquery) + css3 (with -webkit prefix);

example

http://jsfiddle.net/4eujG/

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [jQuery.queue()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.queue/).

Comment: will i ask too much if i ask you a little example :P ? please

Comment: @sbaaaang: What about the example on the documentation page that Matthias linked to?

Comment: i sincerilly can't understand how to use it from the example, since it uses a strange "fx" via queue that i don't know what is :/

Comment: It's just a name of the queue. Like "Maria", "Lucia", "fx" ;)

Comment: @TheFrost come on couldn't be faster and better to put here an example please? i'm troubling with that damn queue but i can't understand very well :(

Answer (score 0):

Using `callback`:

```
var test = function (letter, callback) {
    console.log(letter);

    if (typeof callback !== 'undefined') {
        callback();
    }
};
```

Now you can run it:

```
test('a', function () {
    test('b', function () {
        test('c')
    });
});
```

The result in console is:

```
a
b
c
```

Is it helpful to you?

Comment: thanks but it's not helpfull cause to run your code you need to know how many methods() you'll going to launch, i can't know it should be dynamically queued if possible :P

Comment: function method(a){console.log(a)};method('a');method('b');method('c');does the same.

Answer (score -1):

```
     $( "div" ).promise().done(function() {
     $( "p" ).append( " Finished! " );
     });
```

Hope this example must have  cleared your query

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/rvatC/167/)

Javascript, and most other languages, run code sequentially.

Therefore, they will not both run at the same time.

In fact, it is not possible to run two different pieces of **Javascript** code at the same time. However, in many other languages, it is possible using threads.

However, if they make AJAX calls, the corresponding server-side code called by both functions will run simultaneously.
To prevent that, you'll need to make the first function accept a callback parameter and pass it the second function.

Comment: i need to do it dinamycally i guess queuing is the only solution

Comment: or create sort of methods array then launch it one by one but the problem remains, cause i need to be sure the previous method has finished before to launch the next one